# combobox dropdown window can show beyond the combobox window,how?

Tags: windows, user-interface, gdi+, gdi, winapi

in windows, how can make a 'child' window beyond the parent window, and the parent window always in active status (GetActiveWindow() return parent), just like the combobox dropdown window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the main points when trying to do this:

- The pop-up is a top-level window which has the same parent as the control. (i.e. The pop-up is not a child of the control. It's not a child-window at all; it's a top-level window, but one without a thick window border etc. so it doesn't look like a normal top-level window.) That's why it can extend outside of the control's boundaries.
- When the pop-up is created it is shown using ShowWindow(hWndPopup, SW_SHOWNA) so that it does not take the input focus. This prevents the parent window from going inactive.
- When the pop-up is created you capture the mouse using SetCapture. You then track where the mouse is and highlight items within the pop-up when the mouse overlaps them. When the mouse button is clicked you act on whatever is under the mouse (or cancel the pop-up if the mouse isn't over it at all). Remember to respond to WM_CAPTURECHANGED, in case something else captures the mouse. And remember to ReleaseCapture when you are done.
- The popup should handle WM_MOUSEACTIVATE by returning MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT.

Comment: but the dropdown window can show beyond all parent. if you take a look on word2010, the popup window can have edit and other control in it. not just let the user "click".

Comment: Because the dropdown is a top-level window it is not bound by the edges of the parent. It's like a message box window, except it doesn't have a thick border. If you want controls within the pop-up then things get complex, unless you're prepared to let the pop-up window take the focus (and deactivate the main window); to avoid that you have to process all mouse movement and clicks yourself and tell the controls what to do (or draw the controls yourself based on what the mouse is doing). At least, that's the only way I know to do it. IMO, letting it take focus is okay if it has controls in it.

Comment: so, we can make the control in it take focus and recv keyboard message, but the container window still in INACTIVE state?

Comment: The pop-up window never takes focus. The container window (or the control that you click to open the pop-up, within the container window) keep the focus and track where the mouse (and forward keyboard input to the pop-up) is while the pop-up is open. (At least, that's one way of doing it. Not sure if it's how real dropdowns and menus are done.)